# Range of $f(x) = x^3 -x^2 +x+1$

Tags: calculus, functions

I've been given a question about the function $f(x) = x^3 -x^2 +x+1$.
I need to find the range of the function.

I know I need to differentiate it and do something with maxima and minima. But I don't understand how.

The derivative is $3x^2 -2x+1$. Maxima correspond to the second derivative $<0$ and minima $>0$.
But then what?

Also what is the general way of finding range of a cubic polynomial?

Comment: Hint: consider $\lim_{x\to\infty} (x^3-x^2+x+1)$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} (x^3-x^2+x+1)$.

Comment: For the range , you do not need the minima and maxima. Every polynomial with odd degree has range $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 1):

Any odd degree polynomial with real coefficients is always surjective since complex roots occur in conjugate pairs we always have at least one real root. Hence onto.

Answer (score 0):

To find Maxima or the Minima of any function, you need to first find $f'(x)=0$ having roots $x_i$ and then if $f''(x_i)<0$ then its $x_i$ is Maxima, if $f''(x_i)>0$ then its Minima, while if $f''(x_i)=0$ then its just a point of inflection.
From that you can figure out the Range, now that is for a general function.
In your scenario, you have a cubic equation, which is continuous in nature, So as x tends to infinity, your polynomial tends to infinity and similarly as x tends to negative infinity, your polynomial tends to negative infinity. And since its continuous, so it should take all values between negative and positive infinity. (IVT)
Hence range is $R$

Edit: As pointed by Arthur correctly in the comments, the Second derivative test cannot be used to predict accurately wheter a point is a Point of Inflection. Its better to use the first derivative test instead in this scenario.
[(Notes On First and Second Derivative Test)](https://calculusresources.weebly.com/uploads/5/4/5/4/5454288/4_teaching_notes_-_maxima_minima_points_of_inflection_concavity__.pdf)

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^4$. We have $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=0$. Is $x=0$ a point of inflexion for this $f$?

Answer (score 0):

> $f(x) = x^3 -x^2 +x+1$.

Note that $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty,~~~\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$$

and $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, by Intermediate Value Theorem, the range of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}.$